# docpad plugin for convert [[ ]] (double square brackets) to link as a wiki

Tags: docpad

I want a docpad plugin for convert [[ ]] (double square brackets) to link as a wiki.

I'm thinking than this is a very usefull plugin, but I don't find this kind of plugins.

The idea is convert this:

```
This is a page with a [[link]]
```

to

```
This is a page with a <a href="link_page.html">link</a>
```

when the content between [[ ]] is exactly the title of one page.

Comment: That's an amazing idea! Shall the links be edit links, or should they just be hrefs to the page between the square brackets?

Comment: My idea is a behaviour very similar to wiki: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Help:Wiki_markup#Links_and_URLs The goal is keeping the links of a site independently of its fiscal structure and develop progressively the site (if a link isn't found is shown simply as text).